# Is there a more efficient way of sensing mouse over a bunch of dots?

Tags: python

```
if mouseX < dotA1.x + 7:
    if mouseX > dotA1.x - 7:

        if mouseY < dotA1.y + 7:
            if mouseY > dotA1.y - 7:
                pygame.draw.circle(win, (20, 255, 20), (dotA1.x, dotA1.y), dotA1.radius)

        if mouseY < dotA2.y + 7:
            if mouseY > dotA2.y - 7:
                pygame.draw.circle(win, (20, 255, 20), (dotA2.x, dotA2.y), dotA2.radius)

        if mouseY < dotA3.y + 7:
            if mouseY > dotA3.y - 7:
                pygame.draw.circle(win, (20, 255, 20), (dotA3.x, dotA3.y), dotA3.radius)
```

If I keep going I'm going to have to copy and paste this and change the variables over a hundred times

I automized creating each of these variables from an object, and I plan to add additional functions when interacting with the dots, so I couldn't just use arrow keys to move around the dots

Comment: Have a list with all dots and iterate over it (performing the checks on every one until you find the correct one)?

Comment: If you chain the checking using `elif` instead of different `if` you wil gain on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would simplify it. You would need to put all your dots in a list. Consider reading about and/or operators to avoid extra if statements and for/while loops to avoid repeating the same code.

```
dots = [dotA1, dotA2, dotA3]
if dotA1.x - 7 < mouseX < dotA1.x + 7:
    for dot in dots:
        if dot.y - 7 < mouseY < dot.y + 7:
            pygame.draw.circle(win, (20, 255, 20), (dot.x, dot.y), dot.radius)
```